# Run a single command at the start of the machine

Tags: linux, init-script

Most unix servers do have services defined as init scripts, on linux in: `/etc/init.d` and on hp-ux in: `/sbin/init.d`.

However, what if I just want a single command to be executed when machine boots?

I could write a service init script for that purpose, but that seems to me too complicated for just one command, which launches a process which performs something and then immediately terminates.

Is there a script, somewhere, in which I can just append a line, similar to autoexec.bat in ms-dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a System V or BSD-like init, you can add a line in `/etc/rc.local` with the command. I suggest you background it (using `&`) so that it does not block further startup.

If you are using `systemd`, be aware that it does not read `/etc/rc.local` by default. You can either write a service to execute `/etc/rc.local`, or make a service file for the command itself. The latter will likely allay some of your worries about creating an entire init script for a single command -- systemd service files are far easier to read than traditional init files, which are generally fully blown shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write a init script you can use [cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/).

Type `crontab -e` and add

```
@reboot  /path/to/command
```

Comment: Note: `@reboot` is non-standard. Your cron daemon may or may not support it.